# How to change a shape file with grids to a 2D grid world for RL?

Tags: python, gis, geospatial, shapefile, gridworld

I have a shape file with multiple grids as polygons. I want to convert this into a 2d gridworld so that I can train an RL agent. I tried different libraries but I am stuck in the part of brain storming.

This is the image of the shape file containing multiple polygons as grids.[image: Img of shp file]

I want to convert this into a 2D gridworld to train an agent.

I used rasterio to convert this into a binary grid but it did not work properly in python.